# MTAThread in C# WPF to call Unmanaged Callback function

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, unmanaged

I have to write an application which calls a callback function from an unmanaged dll. In a windows forms application, callback function works when `[STAThread]` is replaced with `[MTATread]` as follows.

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new MainWindow());
}
```

Following is the code segments:

```
//callback function from unmanaged dll
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public delegate void funNoteInfoCallback(parameters ...);

//calling from MainWindow:

//Initialize and assignement:
funNoteInfoCallback noteInfoCallBakCallback;
noteInfoCallBakCallback = MyOnCallBackNotesInfo;

private static void MyOnCallBackNotesInfo(parameters ...)
{
   //do some stuff
}

//Calling function:
SetNoteInfoCallback(handle, noteInfoCallBakCallback, Handle);
```

My application is written using **WPF** and is there any way that I can make the callback function called.